# Enable RDP while connected via Cisco VPN

Tags: vpn, rdp, cisco-vpn

I have a remote win xp machine to which I connect via RDP. When I open a Cisco VPN connection (4.8 client) on that machine, the RDP connection drops because all traffic is routed over the VPN connection now.

Is there a way to make this work?

me => rdp => winXp => vpn => target

Answer (score 1):

Yup - get the person who administers your VPN connection to allow split tunneling.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to configure split tunnelling on your VPN connection.

Split tunnelliong allows traffic to continue to route to the LAN, and also route through the VPN.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

Here is a configuration example for cisco ASA/PIX:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080702999.shtml

Comment: Ok, so this is something that has to be enabled on the ASA/PIX, there is no way to set that on the vpn client?

Comment: for security issues i believe it cannot be set on the client.